# How do you hide hubs from signalr users?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I have implemented the following javascript code:

```
var comHub = $.hubConnection();
var comHubProxy = comHub.createHubProxy("chatHub");
registerClientMethods(comHubProxy);

comHubProxy.on("onConnected", function (userName, userList, friendList, groupHistory, groupList, clanList, roomId) {

});
comHub.start().done(function () {
    registerEvents(comHubProxy);
});
```

Where registerClientMethods(..) and registerEvents(..) just declare all my server and client methods. It all works perfectly, but my issue is I have two hubs. This one, and my super secret admin one. oh, super secret I wish.

My issue is I was doing a little checking, and I decided I'd inspect this hub connection. And oh, the horror.

```
$.connection.hub.proxies
```

That one line, and hello super secret hub name. Of course, then you can connect and boom hello functions. Now then, yeah they cant just use them, since I have further security measures and checks. But I am uneasy they can even /see/ them! Is there a way to configure my hub setup to only connect to certain hubs depending on the proxy generated? I started attempting it but I'm pretty muddled...

```
var hubConfig = new HubConfiguration();
hubConfig.EnableDetailedErrors = false;
hubConfig.EnableJavaScriptProxies = true;

app.MapSignalR("/signalr", hubConfig);
app.MapSignalR("/secret", hubConfig);

GlobalHost.HubPipeline.RequireAuthentication();
```

Comment: `But I am uneasy they can even /see/ them!`  If you have necessary server-side authorization on the Hub, what are your concerns?  In the end, you assume the client has the ability to view anything you send to them.

Comment: my concern is straight away they have a direct path. it has methods like ban users etc and i'd rather just not have them be able to see in the first place. One less thing to worry about.

Comment: I'd say trust your authentication.  Maybe make a very specific role for each hub action, that an admin must be in.

Comment: Already have. But let's say somebody managed to brute force attack an admin account. The admin page isnt visible still. You have to know the url. But with the hubs, the methods are already exposed. It's just a weak link I dont like. I know the chances are slim, but they are feasable.

Comment: As @Jonesy said - first and foremost trust your authentication. To hide/split information you can write the proxy yourself. Get the generated proxy and remove the parts you don't want to be visible. Place the .js on the server and disable proxy generation. You can do this for the admin panel and regular users and include the right file in the right webpage.
Note there are also other easy ways to get at least some of the information - for instance if you open dev tools in the browser (F12) you will be able to see exactly what requests are being sent to the host and what are the responses.

Comment: @Pawel can you give an example of how to separate the proxies. And yes, you can see requests you are making with F12 or fiddler, I just dont want them to see one hub. Surely I can somehow hide it, regardless of whether or not you think it's pointless? Thanks

Comment: @user2330270 - the proxies are generated on the server when you invoke `signalr/hubs` (you should have a line that looks like this in your .js file - `<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>`). Get this file (e.g. using a browser) and save on the disk. Then modify the file by removing functions you don't want to expose and turn off proxy generation on the server. Save the modified file on the server and replace the `src` in the line I posted above with the link to the modified .js file you saved on the server. Not it will just hide methods from the client so you add authentication on top of this.